# Strange Caching Happening When Running Python Script From Bat

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I have a Python script that tags MP3's and renames them. It works when assigning sys args via script parameters in Pycharm.

However, when I call the Python file from a bat, parsing in the same two parameters, I get problems with the file rename.

When printing `os.listdir` debugging the script, I see a bunch of old test MP3's that are no longer in the dir.

I've checked I'm referencing the correct dir. But it seems like somehow the list of files is cached and being passed over (since I have a validation check - abstracted function in the second part of the if statement blow).

Could it be possible Windows is caching something, or perhaps the .pyc is?

Here is part of the Python in question...

```
os.chdir(directory)
    for files in os.listdir("."):
        if files.endswith(".mp3") and not the_file_name_is_valid(files):
            log.info("Starting work on: " + files)...
```

When run from the below bat file, `os.listdir(".")` produces a list of files that are not current for the working directory. Yet when the script is run from Pycharm it works perfectly.

Here is the bat

```
echo off
set SET_PREP="set_prep.py"
set DIR=%cd%
set IMAGE="cover_artwork.jpg"
c:\python27\python.exe %SET_PREP% %DIR% %IMAGE%
Pause
```

Why does running my script with command parameters behave differently to using Script Parameters in Pycharm?

Comment: Let me guess: The path of the current working directory has a space in it. Or some other character that needs to be escaped.

Comment: It would be a common error I agree. However if I print listdir I see a list of files from the dir that isn't current (old test files that have since been successfully renamed and deleted).